# Why is my Windows program trying to call main() instead of WinMain()?

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to make my first steps to OpenGL.

However it seems that it will not happen because of this error coming while trying to debug the solution:

> MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *main referenced in function _*_tmainCRTStartup

I understand that the complier wants to see `int main() ...`, but doesn't it see WinMain call?

Here is the code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    HWND hWnd;
} Glab_t;

static Glab_t glab;

char szClassName[ ] = "GLab";

static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}


int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    MSG messages;
    RECT rect;
    WNDCLASSEX wndClass;
    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    int x, y, w, h;

    screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    rect.left = (screenWidth - 582) / 2;
    rect.top = (screenHeight - 358) / 2;
    rect.right = rect.left + 582;
    rect.bottom = rect.top + 358;

    x = rect.left;
    y = rect.top;
    w = 640;
    h = 480;



    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wndClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wndClass.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
    wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);

    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wndClass)) {
        return 0;
    }

    glab.hWnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,
           szClassName,
           "GLab - OpenGL",
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
           x,
           y,
           w,
           h,
           HWND_DESKTOP,
           NULL,
           hInstance,
           NULL 
           );

    ShowWindow (glab.hWnd, nCmdShow);
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I'm using MS Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Comment: The entry point to the program (whether it is `main` or `WinMain`) should be settable in the compilation options, or so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a project of subsystem `Console` instead of `Windows`. Change it from your project properties, and it will work. That's in *Linker -> System -> SubSystem*.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the properties for the project; a `Console` project will generally look for a main() function, whereas a `Windows` project looks for WinMain() instead.